# Failure to record OpenGL window with OBS

Tags: windows, windows-10, opengl, obs-studio

I run OBS, switch to the window to record, and press the hotkey I've assigned to record. Then I wait 3 seconds and press the "stop recording" hotkey. During this whole time I see the desired animation in the window to record.

What I get out of this is a videofile with the correct length, but in the video:

- the OpenGL window does not animate in the video
- the OpenGL window it has the OBS window on top of it

The OBS window was *not* on top of the OpenGL window when I was recording.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Instead of a "Window Capture" source, I now used a "Game Capture" source.